# How to check values from 2 columns as a condition in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I was trying to solve this requirement from a given DB:

> All employees whose salary exceeds 200,000 euros should be assigned to the "Executive Managers" department (with department code 6).

The E/R diagram looks like this:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFXPC.png)

I tried doing this 2 statements, but the first one blocks other values to be put and the second one is not accepted by Oracle. Any ideas?

```
/* OPTION 1 */
ALTER TABLE EMPLEADO ADD CONSTRAINT CHECK (SALARIO>200000 AND NUM_DEP = 6);
ALTER TABLE DEPARTAMENTO CHECK (NUMERO_D = 6 AND NOMBRE_D='Executive Managers');

/* OPTION 2 */
ALTER TABLE EMPLEADO ADD CONSTRAINT CHECK (NUM_DEP = 6 WHERE SALARIO >200000);
ALTER TABLE DEPARTAMENTO CHECK (NOMBRE_D='Executive Managers' WHERE NUMERO_D = 6);
```

Specifically, Oracle SQL Developer throws this error:

`ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, that looks like an `UPDATE` problem, not `ALTER`.

```
update empleado e set
  e.num_dep = (select d.numero_d
               from departamento d
               where d.nombre_d = 'Executive Managers'
              )
  where salario > 2E5;
```

---

Alternatively, you could create a trigger to handle future inserts/updates:

```
create or replace trigger trg_set_EM 
  before insert or update on empleado
  for each row
begin
  if :new.salario > 2E5 then
     select d.numero_d
       into :new.num_dep
       from departamento d
       where d.nombre_d = 'Executive Managers';
  end if;
end;
/
```

Comment: Seems to work but by this way is only possible to update the values that were in the table at the moment, isn´t it?

Comment: Yes, that's how I understood the problem. Trigger might help; see edited answer, please.